# OS X How to recover modified partition

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning

## Situation

I resized my partition from 1.9tb to 1.5tb so that I could use the leftover for a *Time Machine*. When doing this with the Mac HD it will resize the partition and leave everything else intact. I'm finding out the hard way that this isn't the case with my `FAT 32` partitions.

## Question

I know that in certain situations/environments you can restore deleted files but can you restore files of a partition that has been resized? If so how can I do that? In the meantime I'm not going to touch this partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded a free **deep scan** tool which tries to make sense of the residue on the "clean" drive. It found ~30tb of data on my ~2tb drive so that was weird but I still got a lot of *good* data back.

-Safe partitioning

Comment: What was the tool called?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I believe it was http://www.piriform.com/recuva